# How to add textarea and dropdown to array value?

Tags: php, html, arrays, textarea

Hi! I would like to add additional 2 textarea and a dropdown to my array which will be inserted to my mysql database.

I already have a textarea for:

1. name
2. username

and I would like to add

1. password
2. lastname
3. group(this is a dropdown, and i will be getting the data from my groups table in mysql)

Here's what have i got so far:

```
<?php
require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
if($_POST['name'] || $_POST['username'])
{

$array=$_POST['name'];
$array2=$_POST['username'];

foreach ($array as $i => $name) {
    $username = $array2[$i];


//$sql=mysql_query("insert into hobbies(hobby)values('$hobby')")

$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO test(name, username) VALUES ('$name', '$username')";

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());

}
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Jquery Duplicate Fields Submit Form</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="reCopy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#"    onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return     false">remove</a>';
$('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});  
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
.remove {color:#cc0000}
.input{ border: solid 1px #006699; padding:3px}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="background-color:#ffffcc; padding:4px; border:#333 1px solid">9lessons     programming Blog. Topics focused about jquery, ajax, mysql, php and java. <a     href="http://9lessons.info">http://9lessons.info</a></div>
   <form method="post" action="">
   <p class="clone"> <input type="text" name="name[]" class='input'/> 
     <input type="text" name="lastname[]" class='input' id="lastname[]"/> 
     <input type="text" name="username[]" class='input' id="username[]"/> 
     <input type="text" name="password[]" class='input' id="password[]"/>
   <?php
require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$part_id = $_SESSION['part_id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM groups WHERE part_id = '$part_id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '<select name="group" id="group">';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo '<option value="' . $row['group'] . '">'. $row['group'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>'; 
?></p>
   <p><a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a></p>
   <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jonathan, I'm not really getting your question. What I get from the current question is that ur code is really having some substantial flaws. There is only one field for each of `name`, `lastname`,`username` and `password`. Still u r using array to take only one string in the single textbox for each of them.

Your purpose is even not clear from ur question.

Improve it please.

Comment: The array would be useful if u have to take multiple `name, lastname,username and password` through i/p. So **using array** in `name, lastname,username and password` is useless. isn't it????

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Step back from the code for just a second, and tell us in plain English.

Comment: hi guys, hmm what i achieved here is that i have a from with textarea= name, lastname, username, password and 1 dropdown. there is also a function there where i can add another row of the same field for me to insert multiple data at the same time. As of now the codes works only for name and username, i would like to include password, lastname and the dropdown from the process. i hope this could help. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan, Not trying to be offensive, but I think you are working off of a sample that is just messing you up.  I also suspect english isn't your first language.

1) look closely at an example of creating a form, then responding to its data.  Look at http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson11.php   You will be using the post method for submitted data.

2) Next take a look at database design, particularly first normal form.  See if you can find an example of why that's important.  You need to understand how to create a table to support a "many to many" relationship. (Hint, one user can have multiple hobbies, they could have three, or five or just one hobby.  How do you manage that in a database?) I'm asking you to do this because when you understand how to make duplicate entries store correctly, you will then be ready to ask your users the appropriate questions to obtain the data you need, as simple as possible.

3) I want you to learn how to use PDO (php data object) notation for the database handling.  Its not all that difficult, and will definitely help if any problems arise.  The PDO stuff give much better feedback. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

4) You will need to study up a little bit on security, logins and sessions.

5) Your title "Jquery Duplicate Fields Submit Form" confuses the heck out of me... if something is a duplicate, why does that have to be submitted?  When I get a duplicate, I generally throw the excess away.

6) while we're on the subject of jquery, I'd also recommend doing the try.jquery.com tutorial. that will help you greatly on jquery and also CSS.  You will learn how to hide and unhide fields on the user form (so you don't have to even use that function removelink)  Obviously if the user can't see the field they can't fill it in.

I'd almost rather see you toss the entire file (that I think you've copied from somewhere else) and start from scratch then go down the path you are currently on.

(Left arrow, exclamation point--   html comments  --> and //php comments are your friends when first starting out.  Design what you want the files to do using simple comments and logic structure on what you want your file to do.  Then go back and code to your plain english descriptions.

I will tell you that if you are copying something and you've got more than one or two concepts that you don't understand you will absolutely fail. Better to take the time, learn slow and understand what's going on.

Things that tell me you are just starting out.
The whole array / array2 thing seems to make no sense. 
If you already have some fields from users, and want to fill out more, then on the form page, have your program fill out the fields that you already know.    Remember its pretty easy to have items on your form that are hidden.. If you want to unhide something that's pretty easy to do via javascript

I will say, its certainly possible that you are on top of your stuff, and my interpretation is solely based on english translation differences. In that case profuse apologies.  No offense is intended with my response.  I would like to see you able to help yourself and understand exactly what is going on.

Good luck with it.

Comment: tl;dr, but +1 for your commitment writing an answer that voluminous.